# OpenCart VQMod XML file not working

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

I want to add some content in footer file using VQMod my XML file has the following content but it's not working

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
<id>VQMOD CODE test data</id>
<version>1.0</version>
<vqmver>2.0.1</vqmver>
<author>authore name</author>
<file name="catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.tpl">
<operation error="skip">
<search position="after"><![CDATA[
</footer>
]]></search>
<add><![CDATA[
this is test content
]]></add>
</operation>
</file>
</modification>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is version of your opencart ?
it's dependent of your footer.tpl content. you need to make sure that `</footer>` is available in footer.tpl

and also you need to check in `vqmod/logs` you will see error log there.

Comment: my opencart Version is 2.0.1.1 and allready check in log file but there is no error and footer.tpl file already this tag

Comment: i just tested it and work. try to remove error="skip"

Comment: Its working fine in my another opencart installation but not in current opencart setup i have just install opencart 2.0 and its working fine can you please tell me the reason for it or please tell me the which vqmode version in install for the opencart 2.0.1.1  so that its working fine

Comment: you can use the latest version of vqmod. so many reason vqmod not work properly in template may because template structure and also vqmod install is not work fine.

Comment: Thanks friend for your valualbe suggestion if you dont mind can you give me your gmail id or can you add me on gmail id goyal.deepak1986@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me if any custom theme is applied on top of your default opencart theme?

Edit :
Try this code, it'll work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE modification [
    <!ENTITY adminFolder "admin">
    <!ENTITY themeFolder "default">
    ]>
<modification>
<version>1.0</version>
<vqmver>2.X</vqmver>
<author>umesh</author>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/&themeFolder;/template/common/footer.tpl">
    <operation info="To add custom data at footer">
        <search position="after" ><![CDATA[
               </footer>
                    ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            test content
                    ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```